# rpc remote proceduer compile error

Tags: c, linux, rpc

I'm working on a rpc sample program on linux. When I try to compile my remote procedure I get this error :

```
msg_proc.c:10:7: error: conflicting types for ‘printmessage_1’
In file included from msg_proc.c:8:0:
msg.h:22:15: note: previous declaration of ‘printmessage_1’ was here
```

This is the command I used to complie :

```
cc msg_proc.c msg_svc.c -o msg_server -lnsl
```

And these are my header and procedure files :

```
/*msg.h
 *
 * Please do not edit this file.
 * It was generated using rpcgen.
 */

#ifndef _MSG_H_RPCGEN
#define _MSG_H_RPCGEN

#include <rpc/rpc.h>


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


#define MESSAGEPROG 0x20000001
#define PRINTMESSAGEVERS 1

#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
#define PRINTMESSAGE 1
extern  int * printmessage_1(char **, CLIENT *);
extern  int * printmessage_1_svc(char **, struct svc_req *);
extern int messageprog_1_freeresult (SVCXPRT *, xdrproc_t, caddr_t);

#else /* K&R C */
#define PRINTMESSAGE 1
extern  int * printmessage_1();
extern  int * printmessage_1_svc();
extern int messageprog_1_freeresult ();
#endif /* K&R C */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* !_MSG_H_RPCGEN */


/*
 * msg_proc.c: implementation of the
 * remote procedure "printmessage"
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "msg.h"

int * printmessage_1(char **msg, struct svc_req *req) {
    static int result; /* must be static! */
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("/dev/console", "w");
    if (f == (FILE *) NULL) {
        result = 0;
        return (&result);
    }
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", *msg);
    fclose(f);
    result = 1;
    return (&result);
}
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: The argument types in your `printmessage_1` function match the declaration of `printmessage_1_svc`, not `printmessage_1`.

Comment: thanks my was problem solved. I have to use printmessage_1_svc instead of printmessage_1 in my client application.

Answer (score 1):

The argument types in your `printmessage_1` function match the declaration of `printmessage_1_svc`, not `printmessage_1`. – Barmar